# Return True Values For Spaces in Variables

Tags: php, function, return, whitespace

I have a function "isValid" that is responsible for searching for spaces in all variables provided. I want the function to return true if none of the variables contain spaces. Would this be the right approach?

```
return !(strpos($this->email, " ") || strpos($this->confirm_password1, " ") || strpos($this->handle, " ") || strpos($this->phone, " "));
```

Comment: This would be a great time to investigate unit testing and phpunit.

Comment: The manual states clearly, in a big red box: "Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function"

Comment: Did I miss something here. What does OP has to do with unit testing? @marvo

Comment: @PeeHaa, he has a question that, had he set up a unit test, would have been answered.  That's why I made the suggestion.

Comment: Is the syntax I wrote incorrect?

Comment: @GarethL. Can you show me where this is in the manual please? That is the first I have heard to use a === operator. I was informed it the function strpos() would return true or false.

Comment: You need to compare with "===". Strpos returns the first position (starting from zero). If the user starts his email address with a space, strpos would return 0 (!== false), and your function would return true.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php in the red box that says "warning"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for it to be easily maintainable I would do something like the following:

```
public function isValid()
{
    $properties = array(
        'email',
        'confirm_password1',
        'handle',
        'phone',
    );

    foreach ($properties as $property) {
        if ($this->containsSpace($property)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

private function containsSpace($property)
{
    return !(strpos($this->$property, '') === false);
}
```

Note the [`=== false` as check for `strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php). Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/0ZgNZq.

Note that this only checks for spaces and not possible other whitespace characters. If you want to check for other whitespace characters I would suggest to use a simple regex:

```
private function containsSpace($property)
{
    return (bool)preg_match('/\s/', $this->$property);
}
```

And finally if you really want to do it your original way I would do something like:

```
public function isValid()
{
    return strpos($this->email, " ") === false && strpos($this->confirm_password1, " ") === false && strpos($this->handle, " ") === false && strpos($this->phone, " ") === false;
}
```

Comment: What other whitespace characters do you think there are?

Comment: I have no idea where the data is coming from or what it contains, so it would be impossible for me to tell you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function isValid($var) {
  if (strpos($var, ' ') === false) {
    // Does not contain a space character.
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return (strpos($this->email, " ") === false && strpos($this->confirm_password1, " ")  === false && strpos($this->handle, " ") === false && strpos($this->phone, " ") === false)
```

but this makes for fairly unreadable code...